# How to convert an A5 document (PS or PDF) to an A4 document (PDF)?

Tags: pdf, tex-core, ps

I have a document with A5 pages (created from a TeX file) and want to combine pairs of A5 pages to A4 pages. That is, *without scaling*, page 1 and 2 of the A5 document should become page 1 of the A4 document, and so on. The output has to be a PDF file. How to do this?

[image]

---

Here is an example TeX file, say `a5pages.tex`. The PDF file is created by `pdflatex a5pages.tex` and the PS file is created by `latex a5pages.tex; dvips a5pages.dvi`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=15mm,bmargin=5mm,lmargin=9mm,rmargin=9mm}
\newenvironment{changemargin}{%
  \begin{list}{}{%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
    \setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5in}\setlength{\topsep}{-0.2in}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{-9mm}\setlength{\rightmargin}{-9mm}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\parindent}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{\parindent}
    \setlength{\parsep}{\parskip}%
  }%
  \centering\item[]%
}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}
This is a line of text.
\begin{changemargin}
\rule[1ex]{1\paperwidth}{2pt}

aaa\hfill bbb
\end{changemargin}

\newpage
This is a line of text.
\begin{changemargin}
\rule[1ex]{1\paperwidth}{2pt}

aaa\hfill bbb
\end{changemargin}
\end{document}
```

My attempts to convert the PS or PDF file to an A4 document have been

1. using Acrobat Reader: It is possible to print "Multiple pages per sheet" (Pages per sheet: "2") to a PS file, say `a4pages.ps`, but the result is shifted / wrongly cropped (e.g., the `BoundingBox` is stated as `19 36 576 833`). Changing this value by hand to `0 0 596 842` and possibly changing some other values like `DocumentPaperSizes` corrects this. The problem is that the result was *scaled down*...
2. using `psnup` of the package "psutils"

   ```
   psnup -Pa5 -pa4 -nup 2 a5pages.ps a4pages.ps
   ```

   The file "a4pages.ps" is on a5 paper despite the option `-pa4`. That is probably a bug as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/psutils/+bug/396025). Changing the BoundingBox and possibly other values corrects the problem for the PS file.

Finally, for attempt 1 or 2, to get a PDF file, I followed [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15946864/2469301). That is, a correct PDF file is created by `ps2pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=596  -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=842 a4pages.ps` (where `ps2pdf` is from the package "ghostscript").

Is there a simple way than editing the BoundingBox and possibly other values?

Comment: Have you tried [pdfpages](http://mirror.math.ku.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) for LaTeX?  It lets you insert pages from another PDF into a LaTeX document.

Comment: @kgraney No. I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 4):

As kgraney suggested what you want is easy to do with [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages). One you have your `a5pages.pdf`, create a new one (let's say `a4pages.tex`) with

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,landscape]{a5pages}
\end{document}
```

where `pages=-` will include all pages, `nup=1x2` will place 2 a5pages one beside the other over an a4 page and `landscape` will generate a a4 landscape. Compile it with `pdflatex a4pages.tex` and you'll get

[image]